# get key:value pair inside sub-blocks

Tags: javascript, json, postman, postman-pre-request-script

I have the below output from Postman or hitting end point(we can say).

```
{
  "SearchResult": {
    "total": 11,
    "resources": [
      {
        "id": "12345",
        "name": "GuestType",
        "description": "Identity group ",
      },
      {
        "id": "56789",
        "name": "Admin",
        "description": "",
      },
    ]
  }
}
```

I want to extract `"id"` and `"name"` from these values. I see the values are inside sub-blocks.
How to extract these key-value using java-script that need to be put in "Tests" tab in postman?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
let ids = data.SearchResult.resources.map(obj => obj.id);
let names = data.SearchResult.resources.map(obj => obj.name);
```

```js
let data={ "SearchResult": { "total": 11, "resources": [ { "id": "12345", "name": "GuestType", "description": "Identity group ", }, { "id": "56789", "name": "Admin", "description": "", }, ] } }

let ids = data.SearchResult.resources.map(obj => obj.id);
let names = data.SearchResult.resources.map(obj => obj.name);

console.log(ids);
console.log(names);
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var obj={
  "SearchResult": {
    "total": 11,
    "resources": [
      {
        "id": "12345",
        "name": "GuestType",
        "description": "Identity group ",
      },
      {
        "id": "56789",
        "name": "Admin",
        "description": "",
      },
    ]
  }
}


obj.SearchResult.resources.forEach((o)=>console.log(o.id,o.name));
```

Comment: Thats great. Its working. Here can you help me in assigning each value to a variable(array) and print

Comment: @impika Not Clear what you are asking for..Can you please tell the exact format you want the output

Comment: I want to match the id and name separately. eg: id[0]="12345", name[0]="GuestType"
similarly for id[1] and name[1]
so i need the values to be assigned in array

Comment: @impika Using map is the correct way if you want the result in array,It is already answered by Kamil Kiełczewski..

Answer (score 1):

Below code will return array of objects with id and name only.... Happy coding :)

```
let data = {
  "SearchResult":
  {
    "total": 11,
    "resources": [
      { "id": "12345", "name": "GuestType", "description": "Identity group ", },
      { "id": "56789", "name": "Admin", "description": "", }
    ]
  }
}

let ids = data.SearchResult.resources.map(obj => {
  id: obj.id,
  name: obj.name
});
```

Comment: Thats great. Its working. Here can you help me in assigning each value to a variable(array) and print

Comment: Could you please brief what exactly you are looking for with a code example, so it would be more easy for me to get?